# prove a function is integrable not just with limits

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

In Adams book we see a definition:

if it is just one $I$ that for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ we have:
$L(f,P)$$<=$$I$$<=$$U(f,P)$ we say that f is integrable in $[a,b]$.but we see that every one prove this by saying that $L(f,P_{n})=U(f,P_{n})$ ($n\rightarrow\infty$).

how this two are equal.(as Adams book say after we prove that the limits are equal we should prove that for every partition of $[a,b]$ I is between $L$ and $U$. so one part of proof is incomplete)

Comment: The $P$ is for "every $P,$", and this would include all the $P_n$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: @coffeemath no for example for $[0,1]$ they set $P$=$i/n$.  it is clear that $i/n$ doesn't give all the numbers between $0$ and $1$

Comment: If a statement holds for every partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ then it in particular holds for each partition $P$ made from equally spaced values $i/n.$

Comment: @coffeemath  if we prove it is true for equally spaced values i/n it doesn't mean it is true for all p and everywhere they prove the second one.

Comment: As I recall there are quite a few steps to show the two definitions are equivalent, and I suggest consulting a good treatment of the Riemann integral.